# Does every element need to be placed inside row and column when using Foundation or Bootstrap grid?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, frontend, theory, bootstrap-4

This is kind of theoretical question. I'm familiar with Foundation and recently with Boostrap too. I was wondering does each element on the website have to be placed inside .row>.column (for Foundation) or .container>.row>.col-*-* (for Bootstrap) even if I don't need the grid for this element, for instance when I want to have "back to top" button fixed in the bottom corner of the site (like below)? Will it be semantically correct?

```
html:

<button class='my-button'>scroll to top</button>


css:

.my-button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  //some other styling
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, everything doesn't *have* to come within a `.row` or column element.

`.row` and `.col-*-*` are simply utility classes provided by BootStrap to help you layout your page. They are named so to easily remember them. They provide no additional information about the element/page and could just as well be called `.my-big-fat-row`, etc.